# I cannot decode or extract any information from this string

Tags: php

How to decode the following string so I can extract readable data from it:

```
"H4sIAAAAAAAAAEWRz3LaMBDG…HXHYhZxEsNvDIH3B4ACAAA="
```

The only thing that I know about this string is that it may be random generated bytes, that's all I know, unfortunately.

I tried `base64_decode()` but that didn't work it just gave me this string:

```
?E??r?0?q??D??? }??? 

echo base64_decode("H4sIAAAAAAAAAEWRz3LaMBDG…HXHYhZxEsNvDIH3B4ACAAA=");
```

This string should give me really useful information for the API project I'm working on, also if there is an alternative way to do this using javascript please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: can you post the encryption code or from where you are getting this encrypted string

Comment: https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=09828659-42c5-4360-9203-d93bcb5df79d
on the first auction you will find something called "item_bytes"

Comment: 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 ... is this the string you are looking to decode?

Comment: Decode in `javascript` or `php`?

Comment: Yes exactly.  this is what im looking for

Comment: Decode in any of them but php is preferred

Comment: okay let me edit my answer in php give me some time

Comment: Not sure what contents it has, but `echo file_get_contents('compress.zlib://data://text/plain;base64,'.$text);` shows something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched for H4sIAAA and found `gzdecode()` which decoded this string, thank you for your help Pavan Kumar.

```
$string = "H4sIAAAAAAAAABWPQU+DQBCFH7RVICaeTDyZ7cGrB5PGM4XVNhLiofXaTGGkG2Fp2MXIL+J/8MOM27m9b95M3ouAEJ6KAHg+fFV6bx4WSdtr60WYWapCzFkXJ1xmhnCjSn6tqTJO/kW4LpU51zQ4V9Z2HDi6wMM0vmx10TEZNsKeWJgzcynaLzG0fYel2zdKq1aL4yCmkZ5Xjw49ib2uVaMsl7hxOu07ss60dE+jaVxNYy0/tkmAeU4N494h6ZKRdgciox8S6774ZosIt/LXdhRb26ljb9kEl2q4k3myifOdTA9Z/Bkf1vvkXe4AH1cpNVTxpeM/Fr19kRIBAAA=";


echo gzdecode(base64_decode($string))

//Result i idGCount tag ench HideFlags� display Lore     §7Increases the speed of your!§7minion by §a25%§7. Unlimited§7Duration! §5§lEPICName§5Enchanted Lava Bucket ExtraAttributesidENCHANTED_LAVA_BUCKETDamage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get quite close using the following:

```
function inspect( $s ){
    $b=rawurldecode( base64_decode( trim( $s ) ) );
    $g=gzdecode( $b );
    return sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($g,1));          
}

$i=0;
$max=10;

$url='https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=09828659-42c5-4360-9203-d93bcb5df79d';
$data=file_get_contents( $url );
$json=json_decode( $data );

foreach( $json->auctions as $obj  ){
    echo inspect( $obj->item_bytes );
    if( $i >= $max )break;
    $i++;
}
```

sample output:

```
    i
idGCount
tag    ench  HideFlags�
display    Lore§7Increases the speed of your!§7minion by §a25%§7. Unlimited§7Duration!
§5§lEPICName§5Enchanted Lava Bucket
ExtraAttributesidENCHANTED_LAVA_BUCKETDamage
```